# Convert ParameterInfo[] to RouteValueDictionary via LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

Basically, I need to convert an array of `ParameterInfo[]` to a `RouteValueDictionary`, using LINQ.

I'm getting the `ParameterInfo[]` array from a `MethodInfo` object (via reflection), by calling `obj.GetParameters()`, and I need a `RouteValueDictionary` object from that.

I tried this, but unfortunately it is not working:

```
new RouteValueDictionary(obj.GetParameters().Select(r => new { r.Name = r.DefaultValue }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RouteValueDirectory`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary(v=vs.110).aspx) has a constructor that gets a dictionary and:

> Initializes a new instance of the RouteValueDictionary class and adds elements from the specified collection.

Therefore use linq's [`ToDictionary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx) to form the dictionary and then the matching constructor:

```
new RouteValueDictionary(obj.GetParameters().ToDictionary(key => key.Name, 
                                                          value => value.DefaultValue }))
```